# How can I progressively detect that a touch-enabled device supports overflow scrolling?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, progressive-enhancement, android-3.0-honeycomb

Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) now properly [supports overflow scrolling](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html#UserFeatures) in its browser. In older versions of Android, I've had to write my own JavaScript to scroll content within internal frames, overflowed content, and other elements to compensate for this issue. This shortcoming has been documented in the Android bug tracker with issues [2118](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118), [6864](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6864), [7776](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7776), and a few other similar issues.

With the new release of Android, I'd prefer the browser handle this feature itself, if it's capable. Is there a way to sniff for support of this aside from just sniffing the user agent? I'd prefer to check for support of the feature over hacky user agent sniffing.

I've tried checking support of the `scroll` event, but both old Android browsers and Honeycomb seem to already have this event.

jQuery mobile also doesn't seem to check for support of overflow scrolling. They only detect whether or not the device supports touch events.